# C# AES decrypt serialized object then deserialize it

Tags: c#, encryption, serialization, aes

I got some problems when trying to decrypt and deserialize data.

When i use only serialization and deserialization to file - everything is working fine. When i start to use encryption and decryption i get error :
***Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.***

The thought path:
Object -> Serialize -> Encrypt -> File
File -> Decrypt -> Deserialize

Below methods i use.

My encryption and serialization method:

```
public static void EncryptDataToFile(object data, string filePath, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
           using(Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fs, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        XmlSerializer serializer = new(typeof(UserSettings));
                        serializer.Serialize(cryptoStream, data);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

My decryption and deserialization method:

```
public static UserSettings DecryptDataFromFileAsync(string filePath, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
            using(Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
                using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    using( var cryptostream = new CryptoStream(fs,decryptor,CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        XmlSerializer deserializer = new(typeof(UserSettings));
                        return (UserSettings)deserializer.Deserialize(cryptostream);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to call FlushFinalBlock on the CryptoStream. If you serialize before that your stream is incomplete (in case of AES its missing the padding) and can't be decrypted.

Comment: @Ralph I'm still not sure that `FlushFinalBlock` is called or not. The `using` clause makes sure that `Stream.Dispose` is called, and will call `Flush` but I'm not sure if that will also call `Close` which would call `FlushFinalBlock`. The MS API is such a mess w.r.t. documentation and design...